# Missing "asm/types.h" or "asm-generic/types.h" : fatal error : No such file or directory

Tags: kernel, compiling, sdk

I am trying to compile my sdk(switching development kit) code on ubuntu 14.04.

When I am doing make, I am getting the following error :

```
/lib/modules/3.13.0-32-generic/build/include/uapi/linux/types.h:4:31: fatal error: asm-generic/types.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

I changed the `asm/types.h` to `asm-generic/types.h`. Still I am getting the same error.

Also, I created the soft-link between `asm-generic` and `asm`. That also didn't work.

Need help to solve this issue.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks